# Cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:53007 while using undetected_chromedriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, undetected-chromedriver

I am trying to use [undetected_chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver) for bypassing Cloudfare Protection.

This is the simple code I am trying to use

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

url = 'https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6b0e974952c7df4270cfb4aac332042af9b72c487e42d0bc04a676134118c1ac'

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.title)
```

**However, I get the error :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
  File "/root/tx_sniper/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 401, in __init__
    super(Chrome, self).__init__(
  File "/root/tx_sniper/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/root/tx_sniper/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/root/tx_sniper/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 269, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/root/tx_sniper/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 589, in start_session
    super(selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver, self).start_session(
  File "/root/tx_sniper/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 360, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/root/tx_sniper/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 425, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/root/tx_sniper/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:58911
from chrome not reachable
Stacktrace:
#0 0x5622d155aad3 <unknown>
#1 0x5622d12ba3ff <unknown>
#2 0x5622d12a8ab9 <unknown>
#3 0x5622d12e0f69 <unknown>
#4 0x5622d12d8ee6 <unknown>
#5 0x5622d13142ba <unknown>
#6 0x5622d130e4e3 <unknown>
#7 0x5622d12e3d1a <unknown>
#8 0x5622d12e4e75 <unknown>
#9 0x5622d1588efd <unknown>
#10 0x5622d15a219b <unknown>
#11 0x5622d158ac65 <unknown>
#12 0x5622d15a2ec8 <unknown>
#13 0x5622d157e360 <unknown>
#14 0x5622d15bea68 <unknown>
#15 0x5622d15bebe8 <unknown>
#16 0x5622d15d87fd <unknown>
#17 0x7f129a6566db <unknown>
```

**I am using the following versions :**

Python 3.8

Google Chrome : 100.0.4896.75

ChromeDriver : 100.0.4896.60

undetected-chromedriver : 3.1.5.post4

selenium : 4.1.3

Comment: Selenium version?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Sure, I will do it right now. Thanks for suggesting

Comment: @undetectedSelenium selenium==4.1.3

Comment: @furas I have edited my question again.

Comment: as I know `etherscan` has API for programmers so you could get data without using selenium - and it would work faster.

Comment: Yes @furas , I have used it's API. Actually, my main motive is to bypass Cloudfare Protection. And I saw that etherscan is protected and just wanted to bypass it.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Can you please check the edits and suggest some solution?

Comment: Are you able to initiate successfull session with the normal chrome/chromedriver?

Comment: Yes.. it works with normal webdriver of Selenium

Comment: if you can do it with API then use API  and don't worry about protection. API shouldn't use any protections because it has to run with any library/module.

Comment: Please understand @furas I don't want to do anything with the API. Just forget about Etherscan. I just wanted to know how to bypass Cloudfare Protection.

Comment: Can you please check the reply and suggest some solution? @undetectedSelenium

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use chrome's default userdata-dir, for example: `/home/vncuser/.config/google-chrome`

I met the same problem sometimes, what I need to do just delete the preference file in the userdata-dir:

```
rm ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences
```

If the 'Preferences' file is too large(1~3 GB), the chrome will crash. The normal size of that file would be only a few KBs.

Comment: Hi, may I ask where does this /.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences locate in?  Is it inside the google-chrome folder?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, while testing some new urls to scrape..

All was going well, until all the sudden I got the error :

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:58911
from chrome not reachable
Stacktrace: blablabla
```

Did as Chikong Ho suggested:

 My profile folder was about 3 gig, so I **delete my profile folder**, and it runs like a charm again :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, may I ask where does this /.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences locate in?  Is it inside the google-chrome folder?